# Unable to set initialValue on final form array

Tags: react-final-form, final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I'm having problems setting the initialValue of a `FieldArray` component in React Final Form.  It works when I set it on the `Form` component, but not on the `FieldArray`.  Please see below CodeSandbox examples:

On FieldArray:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-field-arrays-vq9pz

On Form:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-field-arrays-v90nn

I would prefer to have it set on the FieldArray, which seems like it should be possible if I look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form-arrays#initialvalue-any).  Has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `initialValue` was [introduced](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form-arrays/commit/16f19c538acb62f0410ad6aaf69ccd386fded0a0) in version `3.1.3`.

Change the version of `react-final-form-arrays` to `3.1.3` in the sandbox.

You will also need to change the version of `react-final-form` to `6.5.2`

Answer (score 0):

You can define `const customer = { firstName: "test", lastName: "test" };` and then use it in here:

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => push("customers", customer)}>
  Add Customer
</button>
```

Here is CodeSandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-field-arrays-vmmf3?fontsize=14.

Comment: I want the form to render with these values populated and these initial fields.

Comment: Then I guess you need to pass `initialValue` to the Field itself and not to the FieldArray, as stated in here https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FieldConfig#initialvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I will create a mutator like this:

```
   <Form
     mutators={{
       ...arrayMutators,

       addCustomer: (_, state, { changeValue }) => {
         changeValue(state, "customers", (v) => [
           ...v || [],
           { firstName: 'abc', lastName: 'efg' },
         ]);
       },

     }}
     ...
```

and change the Add Customer button `onClick={() => form.mutators.addCustomer()}`